# PHP generated .ics file loads then deletes in iCal immediately

Tags: php, gmail, icalendar

I am using PHP to generate an .ics calendar file for download. I can double click the file and iCal seems to recognise it OK as it asks me which calendar to assign it to. Once I choose this it appears to add the event to the calendar, but almost instantly it is removed again.

This only happens when I select a gmail calendar to assign it to.

Here is the file, what am I missing that Google seems to be anal about?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:7ef5459b7f5c7b9a699e08c92153bed0alexcrooks.me
CLASS:PUBLIC
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTAMP:20120521T091949Z
CREATED:20120521T091949Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120823
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120823
SUMMARY:Some wedding or something?
DESCRIPTION:Some wedding or something?
LAST-MODIFIED:20120521T091949Z
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I have validated my .ics file here:

http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/?url=http%3A%2F%2Falexcrooks.me%2Fdownload%2F9ef24337cf0dd90728039c1d097ddf59.ics

and here:

http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/?id=634731889258508106

Answer (score 1):

OK it turns out it is working fine, however you need to press refresh manually (or wait for auto refresh) for the event to re-appear!